# Querying Open Graph objects and actions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I've created a few actions and object types for my application. For this question's purpose, let's assume I have an `myapp:book` custom type (where `myapp` is my application's namespace and `book` is the custom type) and a `myapp:read` action.

Is is possible answer any of the following queries using Facebook's Graph API (or any other FB API)?

1. List all objects of type `myapp:book`. By that, I mean retrieve a list all pages that FB's scraper has stored which have an `go:type` of `myapp:book`.
2. List all actions that involve objects of type `myapp:book`.
3. List all `read` actions that occurred in my app. By that, I mean retrieve a list of all actions that were posted to FB which have an `action_type` of `myapp:read`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware: no, no and no

Your own databases should have all of that information already though, depending on how you've implemented the app, certainly the first two if not necessarily the third

You can retrieve, for a given user, the list of actions of a particular type, but not 'all actions' or 'across all users'