# Get total number of Custom Actions on Open Graph Object

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I want to access number of custom actions (that I've defined) done on my Open Graph object. Facebook will return number of Like actions in response(like [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=?ids=http://www.yourpage.com)) but they don't include number of custom actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps can retrieve actions published for the authorized user. For example, a Recipe app can retrieve all the recipes I've cooked or plan on cooking and customize the app experience based the data.

This API returns the action’s metadata including timestamps along with custom properties and their values. Objects referenced from an action are returned a single level deep.

```
GET /{action-instance-id}
```

The following retrieves a specific action instance

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{action-instance-id}?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Response

```
{
    "id": "1538292028372"
    "start_time": 1303502229, 
    "end_time": 1303513029, 
    "data": {
        "type": "recipebox:recipe", 
        "url": "http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html", 
        "id": "1234567890", 
        "title": "Pumpkin Pie"
    }, 
}
```

The above content is from [FB Documentaion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publish-action/#read)

Comment: I want total number of actions per object not one detailed action.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978368/querying-open-graph-objects-and-actions -> checkout this link

Comment: So Answer is a 'no, you can't get that data from Facebook'. That's disappointing!